# A Place of War and Battle

Tags: riddle, haiku

> Multicolored land,
> I hold a girl in my hand.
> She dances away.
>
> "YES! I TOOK HER!! HA!!!"
> The opponent brags to me.
> But, he lost the war.
>
> He, the monarch, gone.
> Trapped by my clever soldiers
> And my clever ways.

What are we doing?

Comment: You are/is back. :D

Comment: Yes. MUAHAHAHA!!!!!!! (By the way, nice site design!)

Comment: "What are we doing?" Writing haiku's, it seems! :P --- Okay, I'll try to answer this one seriously now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are

> **Playing Chess**. Your opponent captured your queen, and he is bragging about it. But in reality, it was a queen sacrifice that led to you checkmating the king and winning the game.

Comment: You did it, mate! YAY!!! (Pun intended)

Comment: Clever! Can you explain why you are holding the girl in your hand? The opponent should be the one holding her, because he captured her.

Comment: I moved her there. :P

Comment: Oh, are you saying that between the time where you "held the girl in your hand" and your opponent taking her, you set her down?

Comment: Yes. I felt that "setting her down" would give it away quicker.

Comment: True, just feel like it is leading astray. Constructive criticism, I would suggest changing that one line. :) Nice riddle!

Answer (score 1):

You are

> **Playing a game of Old Maid.** In this card game, players take turns grabbing a card from the other player(s)' hand. If you make a pair from the card you take (as in having two 2's, two Jack's, etc.), both get removed. The trick is that there is one card without a match, the Queen, who is the Old Maid. The game ends when a player is stuck holding the Old Maid and all other cards are removed. That player loses.

Comment: The last haiku doesn't really fit.

Comment: Oho, I thought it said "she, the monarch". My mistake. I'll think a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

@You are

> Playing Tennis

Multicolored land,
I hold a girl in my hand.
She dances away.

> You are in the tennis ground. You have the racket. And you swing it, hitting the ball toward your opponent.

"YES! I TOOK HER!! HA!!!"
The opponent brags to me.
But, he lost the war.

> Opponent hits it but he loses because he sends the ball out of the line.

He, the monarch, gone.
Trapped by my clever solders
And my clever ways.

> Opponent is better than @you, so he is called monarch. And he lost because of your clever shot.

Comment: The last haiku doesn't really fit.